# If $\tan(\alpha)+\cot(\alpha)=a\quad(a\gt 0),$ find $\sqrt{\tan(\alpha)}+\sqrt{\cot(\alpha)}$

Tags: trigonometry, radicals

I multiplied both expressions: $$\tan\bigl(\sqrt{\tan(\alpha)}+\sqrt{\cot(\alpha)}\bigr)+\cot\bigl(\sqrt{\tan(\alpha)}+\sqrt{\cot(\alpha)}\bigr)=\sqrt{\tan(\alpha)}+\sqrt{\cot(\alpha)}\bigl(a\bigr).$$Raising to the second power also didn't help.
The variants are

> A)$\sqrt{a+2}$ B)$a-2$ C)$\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{a}$ D)$a+2$ E)$\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Compute $\left(\sqrt{\tan(\alpha)}+\sqrt{\cot(\alpha)}\right)^2.$

Comment: @mfl It's $a+2\sqrt{tan(\alpha)}\sqrt{\cot(\alpha)}$ and there isn't such an answer.

Comment: @Tug'tekin $\;\tan(\alpha) \, \cot(\alpha) = \,?\,$

Comment: If you say there isn't such an answer it must be a multiple choice problem.  Why did you not supply the choices?

Comment: @RossMillikan Did it!

Comment: @dxiv It is 1, and my expression above will be $a+2,$ but, still, it isn't the right answer.

Comment: @Tug'tekin The ***square*** of your expression will be $a+2$. By the way, you just accepted an answer which says that very same thing.

Comment: This isn't really about tangents and cotangents. The tangent of an angle can be any number at all, and the cotangent is its reciprocal. So the problem is: Given that $x + \dfrac 1 x = a,$ find $\sqrt x + \sqrt{\dfrac 1 x}. \qquad$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\tan\alpha<0$ then $\cot\alpha<0$, which is contradiction because $a>0$.

Thus,  $\tan\alpha>0$, $\cot\alpha>0$ and

$$\sqrt{\tan\alpha}+\sqrt{\cot\alpha}=\sqrt{\tan\alpha+\cot\alpha+2\sqrt{\tan\alpha\cot\alpha}}=\sqrt{a+2}$$

Comment: It turns out that there is a $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}=\sqrt{x+y+2\sqrt{xy}}$ formula. If yes, what does the expression $\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}$ equal to?

Comment: @Tug'tekin In this case we can not use squaring because $\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}$ can be negative. But $|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|=\sqrt{x+y-2\sqrt{xy}}$.

Comment: Is there any other way round to solve this problem?

Comment: @Tug'tekin Yes, but I think my first way is simplest. For example, we can solve the equation $t+\frac{1}{t}=a$, but it's a very ugly way, I think.

Comment: @Tug'tekin, the middle step of the formula is: $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}=\sqrt{(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})^2}=\sqrt{x+y+2\sqrt{xy}}$